# Implement iOS select menu

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to implement a select menu like that (when an user clicks on a button it should appear):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1gqv.png]

How is that menu called and how can I implement it with a storyboard?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called a UIActionSheet

You need to add it programatically, not by storyboard, this is an example of adding a new one:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Title"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                              destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete"
                              otherButtonTitles:@"Option 1", @"Option 2", nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

You can find all the documentation here:

[UIActionSheet Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and by the way it looks like in iOS7 and here are good tutorials how to create it:

http://littlereddoor.co.uk/welcome/blog/beginning-ios-development-create-and-show-an-instance-of-uiactionsheet/

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uiactionsheet_uiactionsheetdelegate/

http://iphone.milktin.com/2013/06/working-with-uiactionsheet.html